# Reporting / Dashboard tool with good User Interface

Tags: user-interface, reporting-services, report, data-visualization, dashboard

I'm looking for a Dashboard tool with best UI, I mean any tool where I could create some UI using HTML5,Jquery and Photoshop in the front end and when ever I change the filters, different charts should appear. Or any tool that contains inbuilt one of the best UI's. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Cyfe](http://www.cyfe.com)?

Cyfe has over 50 built-in integrations with hundreds of metrics (e.g. Google Analytics, Salesforce, Facebook, etc). And you can bring your own data into your dashboards using [custom widgets](http://www.cyfe.com/custom).

Disclaimer: I'm the founder so please pardon the shameless plug.